# Debugging JAXB issues

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I am running into an issue with JAXB 2 when marshaling my objects. I have an XmlJavaTypeAdapter which is working perfectly fine in unit tests, but when I try to marshal the same object graph from a web service (using JAX-WS), the XmlJavaTypeAdapter is being ignored completely. What's the easiest way to debug this problem?

I have a simple standalone project checked into my svn repository that demonstrates this issue. Can somebody please take a look to see if I am doing something obviously wrong? The URL for the project is: http://archfirst.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/examples/jaxb-jaxws-sample. There is a readme.txt file in the root folder that describes the issue in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating your JAXBContext?

Comment: In my unit test, I am simply doing JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Order.class); In the real application, I don't know because a JAX-WS web service is doing the serialization for me. The entire object graph is being traversed, just the adapters are missed.

Comment: I have now verified the issue using a small standalone sample. The problem is definitely with the Web Service not being able to find the adapter. The exact same object is serialized correctly using JAXB directly. Also the issue has nothing to do with multiple jars. My sample is now all in one project. It is checked into my open-source project here: http://archfirst.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/examples/jaxb-jaxws-sample. Could you please take a look to see if I am doing something obviously wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the problem. My unit test was picking up the JAXB implementation in the Java runtime, whereas my web service was picking up the JAXB implementation from GlassFish. Apparently the implementation bundled with GlassFish (2.2.1.1) cannot handle my use case. I proved it by forcing my unit test to use jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar. Also it seems that the bug has been fixed in the latest JAXB implementation (2.2.3-1), but I am struggling to figure out how to replace GlassFish's implementation with this new version (see my post [here](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/upgrading-glassfish-latest-jaxb-implementation)).